# Ignoring file in Github and Django

Tags: django, git, github, gitignore, github-for-mac

Me and my friend are both working on a project in Django. We are beginners with both GitHub as well as Django. We have managed to use .gitignore to ingore certain files. This is how the .gitignore looks like :

```
.DS_Store
groupProject/__pycache__
marketplace/__pycache__
marketplace/migrations/__pycache__
marketplace/templatetags/__pycache__
db.sqlite3
```

The only issue that we have is that when we try to push we get an error saying that there is a merge conflict for this file 'db.sqlite3' . I have added this file in .gitignore and for some reason it still decides to read it?

What should we do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the db.sqlite from the repository with the command:

```
git rm --cached db.sqlite
```

I think this happened because yout ignored the db.sqlite after you added it to the repo ;)